# Tomcat Valve - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: tomcat, tomcat-valve

Tomcat 6.0.36

I am getting a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when starting my tomcat.

I have this in my server.xml :

```
<Host name="dev.spirit.comp.net" appBase="spirit"
                unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false"
                xmlNamespaceAware="false">
                <Alias>dev.spirit.comp.com</Alias>  
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ImprovedAccessLogValve"
                directory="logs/spirit" prefix="${hostname}-${port}.access_log."
                suffix=".txt"
                pattern="%h %v %u %t '%r' %s %b '%{Referer}i' '%{User-Agent}i' '%{Cookie}i'"
                resolveHosts="false" fileDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd.HH" />
```

I am getting this error :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve$LocalAddrElement.<init>(Lorg/apache/catalina/valves/AccessLogValve;)V
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ImprovedAccessLogValve.initElements(ImprovedAccessLogValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ImprovedAccessLogValve.<init>(ImprovedAccessLogValve.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Comment: Did you compile with the same Tomcat as you are trying to run? I would guess a version mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, for some reason there was some jar files in the tomcat server that was from another version